# MySQL - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`areas_conhecimento`.`sub_areas`,

Tags: mysql, sql, json, node.js, chave-estrangeira

Olá, estou fazendo um trabalho que consiste em desenvolver um sistema para gerenciar projetos e etc. Nesse sistema eu preciso ter uma tabela com as areas do conhecimento do cnpq. Estou pegando as Grandes Areas, Areas, Sub-Areas e Especialidades de um arquivo JSON - com todas os dados que eu falei - que eu encontrei no GitHub. Eu consegui inserir as grandes areas e areas tranquilamente mas quando chega nas sub-areas eu tenho como retorno um erro:

```
'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`areas_conhecimento`.`sub_areas`, CONSTRAINT `area` FOREIGN KEY (`area`) REFERENCES `areas` (`codigo`))'
```

Estou usando MySQL com NodeJS, o insert que usei foi:

```
INSERT INTO areas_conhecimento.sub_areas VALUES ('Álgebra', '10100008', '10101004');
```

Onde 10100008 é o codigo de um registro da tabela área.
Segue o código do banco:

```
create database areas_conhecimento;
use areas_conhecimento;

CREATE TABLE categorias (
    nome VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    codigo INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE areas (
    nome VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    categoria INT NOT NULL,
    codigo INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CONSTRAINT categoria FOREIGN KEY (categoria)
        REFERENCES categorias (codigo)
);

CREATE TABLE sub_areas (
    nome VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    codigo INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    area INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT area FOREIGN KEY (area)
        REFERENCES areas (codigo)
);

CREATE TABLE especialidades (
    nome VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    codigo INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    sub_area INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT sub_area FOREIGN KEY (sub_area)
        REFERENCES sub_areas (codigo)
);
```

Onde categoria = Grandes areas e o resto é a mesma coisa.

o arquivo JSON está disponível [aqui](https://github.com/nathanlemos/cnpq-areas-do-conhecimento)

Gostaria de saber como posso resolver esse erro e não perder dados da minha tabela.

Comment: Impossível afirmar com certeza pois você não postou o comando INSERT que apresentou erro, com todos os dados especificados. Aparentemente você está informando um código de área que não existe na tabela areas.

Comment: Não havia percebido rsrs. Editei a pergunta. Em resumo foi o seguinte:
INSERT INTO areas_conhecimento.sub_areas VALUES ('Álgebra', '10100008', '10101004');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com seu arquivo:

```
"areas": [
    {
      "codigo": "10100008",
      "nome": "Matemática",
      "sub-areas": [
        {
          "codigo": "10101004",
          "nome": "Álgebra",
```

mas em seu INSERT você especificou:

```
INSERT INTO areas_conhecimento.sub_areas VALUES ('Álgebra', '10100008', '10101004');
```

isto é para sub_areas:

```
nome: 'Álgebra'
codigo: 10100008
area: 10101004
```

que não parece estar correto, talvez deva ser:

```
INSERT INTO areas_conhecimento.sub_areas VALUES ('Álgebra', '10101004', '10100008');
```

Comment: era isso mesmo, eu só descobri quando especifiquei os dados que queria inserir fazendo "INSERT INTO areas_conhecimento.sub_areas (nome, codigo, area) [...]", eram tantas outras linhas de código que não me atentei a esse erro